# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (simple UDP client-server)

Tags: python, udp

Absolute newbie here, and I can't quite seem to find the answer to my question. Running python 2.7.

My code for the server is as follows:

```
#UDPPingerClient.py
from socket import *

#Create a UDP socket
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
#Assign IP address and port number to socket
clientSocket.bind(("127.0.0.1",9501))

#Set a timeout value of 1 second
clientSocket.settimeout(1)

msg = "test"

#the server info
sIP = "127.0.0.1"
sPort = 12007
addr = (sIP,sPort)

a = 10

# the server will automatically drop some messages
# so we send 10 to make sure it gets there and then
# listen for a response from the server
while a > 0:
    clientSocket.sendto(msg,addr)
    try:
        received, server = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
        print received
    except timeout:
        print ('an error occured')

    a = a - 1
```

The server code:

```
# UDPPingerServer.py 
# We will need the following module to generate randomized lost packets 
import random 
from socket import * 

# Create a UDP socket 
# Notice the use of SOCK_DGRAM for UDP packets 
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM) 
# Assign IP address and port number to socket 
serverSocket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 12007)) 

while True: 
    # Generate random number in the range of 0 to 10 
    rand = random.randint(0, 10) 
    # Receive the client packet along with the address it is coming from 
    message, address = serverSocket.recvfrom(1024) 
    # Capitalize the message from the client 
    message = message.upper()
    12 # If rand is less is than 4, we consider the packet lost and do not respond
    if rand < 4:
        continue 
    # Otherwise, the server responds 
    serverSocket.sendto(message, address)
```

Thus far I haven't been able to get a reply from the server. The most I've been able to accomplish is sending once and timing out before getting this error:

```
an error occured <-- output from exception

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/UDPPingerClient.py", line 23, in <module>
    received, server = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The reproducibility on this one is 100%, this is the outcome every time I run the server file and then the client file. Same thing with the firewall on or off. I have a feeling this has to do with the exception but I can't quite wrap my head around why.

Comment: Works fine on my machine, both on Windows 8 and Linux 3.4.

Comment: Given that UDP is not connexion-oriented, the error message doesn't make sense.  It may be that a problem occurs at a different level (e.g. in some arguably-broken firewall logic) and gets reported wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

this is the output i got:

```
foggy@dew ~ $ python UDPPingerClient.py 
TEST
TEST
an error occured
TEST
TEST
TEST
an error occured
TEST
an error occured
TEST
```

exactly ten messages, some have timeouted others were passed back.
besides that extra 12 above rand line in Server (and that doesn't bother the interpreter) i don't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: try investigating on that error code further. it is probably network related issue, that drops your udp msgs. it's a linux here btw.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this just kind of confirms that the error exists outside of python.[This guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734219/simple-python-udp-server-trouble-receiving-packets-from-clients-other-than-loca) had the same issue that I get running the code he has.

Comment: please try commenting out those two lines in server with `if rand: < 4 continue` since you're not seeding the prng, if your system's one is somehow borked that may be the cause for server to always drop the connection.

Comment: Nah, it's not that. I've tried running the incredibly basic client-server connection that the other user talks about in the link in the above comment and I'm getting nothing on the receiving end. Just a straightforward sendto recvfrom and the packets are lost every time.