# UDP in Jython 2.7

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm trying to write a python function that sends an UDP message to a remote host and receives a reply, but I have a really hard time understaning how to do this.
I've been looking at thread: [Simple Python UDP Server: trouble receiving packets from clients other than localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734219/simple-python-udp-server-trouble-receiving-packets-from-clients-other-than-loca/35483350#35483350)

I understand how to send something, but how to send AND receive in the correct sequence?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ignore, I got it..

```
import socket
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 3001
MESSAGE = "asd"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                 socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
```